Opacity Issues with Dynamic Colors in TailwindCSS
TL;DR
text-primary-500/50 not working as expected.
Declare Dynamic Color
I have a color named primary. This color doesn't have any specific settings; instead, I assign existing colors based on a template. If the parent element has the class theme-red, the primary color should essentially match the red color. If the parent element has the class theme-blue, the primary color should match the blue color. By default, the primary color is red.
I have implemented this in the following example.
Example


tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: {
          500: 'var(--color-primary-500)',
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>
<style type="text/tailwindcss">
  @layer utilities {
    .theme-red {
      --color-primary-500: theme('colors.red.500');
    }

    .theme-blue {
      --color-primary-500: theme('colors.blue.500');
    }
  }
</style>

<div>
  <div class="text-green-500">
    Default Green Color
  </div>
  <div class="text-green-500/50">
    Default Green Color With Opacity
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Not working examples with dynamic primary color -->
<div class="theme-red">
  <div class="text-primary-500">
    Example Red Theme
  </div>
  <div class="text-primary-500/50">
    Example Red Theme With Opacity
  </div>
</div>

<div class="theme-blue">
  <div class="text-primary-500">
    Example Blue Theme
  </div>
  <div class="text-primary-500/50">
    Example Blue Theme With Opacity
  </div>
</div>



Result

Opacity Dynamic Colors Not Working
The issue arises with transparent colors, such as text-primary-500/50. That is, it should be text-primary-500 with 0.5 opacity. It doesn't work because text-primary-500 is essentially a hex color, but in CSS, we expected an RGB color code, which we could then blend with opacity on a 0-1 scale. How can I make it work so that text-primary-500/50 functions similarly to my written logic?
Expected Behavior
I expected primary color to work the same way as the base colors, as shown with the green color in the previous result. Here’s an example of what I would like.


You could consider using color-mix() in your color definition. This allows the use of the Tailwind <alpha-value> token to affect the transparency of a CSS variable that is not in HSL or RGB component format:


tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: {
          500: 'color-mix(in srgb, var(--color-primary-500) calc(100% * <alpha-value>), transparent)',
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>
<style type="text/tailwindcss">
  @layer utilities {
    .theme-red {
      --color-primary-500: theme('colors.red.500');
    }

    .theme-blue {
      --color-primary-500: theme('colors.blue.500');
    }
  }
</style>

<div class="theme-red">
  <div class="text-primary-500">
    Example Red Theme
  </div>
  <div class="text-primary-500/50">
    Example Red Theme With Opacity
  </div>
</div>

<div class="theme-blue">
  <div class="text-primary-500">
    Example Blue Theme
  </div>
  <div class="text-primary-500/50">
    Example Blue Theme With Opacity
  </div>
</div>



Alternatively, you could consider revising the CSS variable definition to be inside a Tailwind plugin. This allows the values to be manipulated to HSL or RGB component format. Then, the <alpha-value> token can be used more "natually" in a rgb() or hsl() CSS function:


tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        primary: {
          500: 'rgb(var(--color-primary-500) / <alpha-value>)',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    tailwind.plugin(({ addBase, theme }) => {
      const toRgb = (hex) => {
        const r = parseInt(hex.substring(1, 3), 16);
        const g = parseInt(hex.substring(3, 5), 16);
        const b = parseInt(hex.substring(5, 7), 16);
        return `${r} ${g} ${b}`;
      };

      addBase({
        '.theme-red': {
          '--color-primary-500': toRgb(theme('colors.red.500')),
        },
        '.theme-blue': {
          '--color-primary-500': toRgb(theme('colors.blue.500')),
        },
      });
    }),
  ],
}
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.5"></script>

<div class="theme-red">
  <div class="text-primary-500">
    Example Red Theme
  </div>
  <div class="text-primary-500/50">
    Example Red Theme With Opacity
  </div>
</div>

<div class="theme-blue">
  <div class="text-primary-500">
    Example Blue Theme
  </div>
  <div class="text-primary-500/50">
    Example Blue Theme With Opacity
  </div>
</div>




Thanks for the answers! Just one more question: which of the two solutions would you prefer and why? The second one seems more appealing to me. You can write a function that allows you to pass variables for every color from 25 to 975 to the function object.

Second does allow more programmatic generation but can get tricky to support different "source" color value formats.
